# DataGridView.CellLeave not recognizing cell contents

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I want the contents of the 4th column to update with the combined contents of columns 1 and 3 when certain conditions are met (mostly just not empty).

Note that if I click on and off of a completed cell it works as expected. It's as if the CellLeave event isn't aware of the finalized contents. The value from Cell(0) is captured correctly the first time. It's the Cell(2) aka current column that isn't.

Here's what I've got:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellLeave

    'Dim CurrentColumnIndex As Integer = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    'Dim CurrentRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex

    If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        If DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value <> "" Then
            DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value & "-" & DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm open to alternative methods, but I've got this one mostly completed so alternatives should be simple.

My desired result:

```
+---+----+-----+       +---+---+-----+
| 1 | a  |     |  ---> | 1 | a | 1-a |
+---+----+-----+       +---+---+-----+
```

My problem:

```
+---+----+-----+       +---+---+-----+      +---+---+-----+
| 1 | a  |     |  ---> | 1 | a | 1-  | ---> | 1 | a | 1-a |
+---+----+-----+       +---+---+-----+      +---+---+-----+
```

Where the first step is what I enter, the second step is what happens when I leave the cell, and the third step is what happens when I re-enter and leave the cell.

Comment: I think you want to look at the event args passed to you.  e.ColumnIndex and e.RowIndex will tell you the cell just left rather than CurrentXXXXX

Comment: @Plutonix I was worried that it would consider the next cell clicked to be the one to calculate but that isn't the case. The formulas work,  only you have to re-enter and exit the cell for them to do so.

Comment: its a matter of context - in a CellLEAVE event it indicates the cell LEFT, if it was the CellENTER, the event args would indicate the cell entered.

Comment: @Plutonix Done. Still not solving my problem, but I can see how that would be better coding practice. I'm trying to figure out how to make a simple table to demonstrate my problem and desired result. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse you will not get the changed value in `CellLeave` event as the changes are not committed yet. In your case, you get the value in the third step because the changed value is committed by then.

If you want to get the changed value then subscribe to `CellValueChanged` event.

```
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
```

In a sample program, I changed a cell value from 1 to 3. See how the events are fired and the value change happening.

1. CellLeave - 1
2. CellValidating - 1
3. CellValueChanged - 3
4. CellValidated - 3
5. CellEndEdit - 3

Comment: I used CellEndEdit, but great answer.